# Mongodb: geospatial indexes and covered index queries

Tags: mongodb

Currently I have an index on a geospatial field in one of my collections set up like this:

```
collection.ensureIndex({ loc : "2d" }, { min : -10000 , max : 10000,
    bits : 32, unique:true}
```

However, I would like to include one more field in the index, so I can take advantage of [covered index queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-CoveredIndexes) in one of my use cases.  An ensureIndex with multiple fields (compound index) looks something like this:

```
collection.ensureIndex( { username : 1, password : 1, roles : 1} );
```

Question is - how do I write my first index spec with an additional field, so that I keep my min/max parameters?  In other words, how to specify that the min/max/bits only apply to one of the index fields?  My best guess so far is:

```
collection.ensureIndex({ loc : "2d", field2 : 1 },
    { min : -10000 , max : 10000 , bits : 32, unique:true}
```

But I have no confidence that this is working as it should!

UPDATE:

There is more info in the documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CompoundIndexes), but it still does not explicitly show how to specify the min/max in this case.

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.getIndexes() should give you the parameters used to construct the index - the min/max/bits field will only ever apply to the "2d" field.

There's no way to see these parameters aside from getIndexes(), but you can easily verify that you aren't allowed to insert the same location/field pair, and that you aren't allowed to insert locs outside your bounds (but field2 can be anything).  The bits setting is harder to verify directly, though you can indirectly verify by setting it very low and seeing that nearby points then trigger the unique key violations.